# Send a movieclip from as3(parent) to as2 in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, communication, send, actionscript-2

I have a **as3** movie which loads an **as2** in it.

I create a movieclip in as3 and i want to pass this created movieclip to as2.

There are some problems:

1 - How to send it from as3 to as2?

2 - How to create a movieclip in as2 with this received data? ( the loadMovie function has just a **url** parameter, not **data** )

Answer (score 1):

As3 runtime cann't operate with code in as2 swfs because they are executed in different AVM runtimes (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-8000.html). No way to pass display object.

However I think it is possible to pass raw data via:

- LocalConnection (sample http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/swfbridge_easie.html);
- usign specific url while loading swfs. For example, as3.swf loads as2.swf?param=paramValue. Then try to read _root._url

Comment: thx for the answer but as i commented on the previous answer i have no problem passing raw data. The problem is passing movieclips.

Answer (score 0):

the only way i know is to try using [`LocalConnection`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html), however i'm not sure you can pass a DisplayObject through it.

Comment: I'm using LocalConnection and I can call a **function( parameter )** from as3 to as2. But how can I pass a movieclip?

Comment: @Arin Aivazian - try `var mc:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip("container", 100); mc = parameterFromFunction;`

Comment: didn't work. when I pass the movieclip as the function and trace it in receiver function it is null. thx anyway

Comment: @Arin Aivazian - if the clip you are passing is created with `Graphics` methods you can pass drawing instructions to as2. it seems the only option